# excel vba value paste all formulas of type "=X()"

Tags: excel, array-formulas, vba

I have a database app that stores data in array formulas through a UDF.

I would like to have a macro that goes through the sheet/wbook and breaks all the external links by replacing the udf array formula with the current value in the given cell.

**The challenge is that cells within a given array formula can't be written individually.** For example a macro like that below will cause the entire array to be destroyed on the first write.

```
Public Sub breaklink()
Dim c
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    Debug.Print c.FormulaArray
    If InStr(c.FormulaArray, "MYFORMULA(") Then
        Stop
        c.FormulaArray = c.Value
        'c.Value = c.Value     --THIS THROWS ERROR 1004 (Can't edit part of an array)
        Stop
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

If there were a cell method like `c.getArrayFormulaRange`, then I could use it to create an array of values and then write-over the array formula.

I could conceivably loop through adjacent cells to attempt to find the bounds of each array, but this seems quite cumbersome (also, I'd be changing the range I was looping through during the loop, which could raise problems).  Is there any method or object property that will help me identify the entire range that is occupied by a given array formula?

Comment: `c.CurrentArray` would return the `Range` of the `FormulaArray` if there is one in `c`.  You could check the presence of an array in `c` with `c.HasArray`.  It will return `True` if there is.

Comment: BTW, you should dim your `c` as a `Range` to have access to the list of methods and properties applicable to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following simpLE MAn's suggestions above, this is my solution:

```
Public Sub breakLinks(scope As String)
Dim formula_tokens()
Dim c As Range, fa_range As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim token
formula_tokens = Array("MYFORMULA1(", "MYFORMULA2(", "OTHERFORMULA(", "OTHERFORMULA2(")
If scope = "sheet" Then
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        For Each token In formula_tokens
            If InStr(UCase(c.FormulaArray), token) Then
                If c.HasArray Then
                    Set fa_range = c.CurrentArray
                    fa_range.FormulaArray = fa_range.Value
                Else
                    c.Formula = c.Value
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

ElseIf scope = "wbook" Then
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each c In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            For Each token In formula_tokens
                If InStr(UCase(c.FormulaArray), token) Then
                    If c.HasArray Then
                        Set fa_range = c.CurrentArray
                        fa_range.FormulaArray = fa_range.Value
                    Else
                        c.Formula = c.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: On this line `Dim c, fa_range As Range`, only `fa_range` will be seen as `Range`.  If you want to declare on the same line, you must do it like this: `Dim c As Range, fa_range As Range`